# How does blanket.js modify JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, code-coverage, blanket.js

The homepage for [blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/) says I only need to data a `data-cover` attribute to my `script` tags.

But how is `blanket.js` supposed to modify the files *before* they are run?

The [documentation](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket#mechanism) on Github says its first step is

> Loading your source files using a modified [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)/Require script.

**Do I have to use `RequireJS` to get blanket.js to work?**

(I cannot find anywhere where this is documented.)

Currently, I do not use requireJS, and currently, `blanket.js` is not working. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago, Blanket used Require.js internally - I don't know if this is still true. Though, require.js was bundled with the `blanket.js` file. So no, you don't need to include require.js.

What you may need to include is an adapter for your Unit test Framework. https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/tree/master/src/adapters

Comment: I tried to write my own adapter and apparently failed. I will take another look.